# Need a shell script that can run a oracle query and produce output in .csv format

Tags: oracle, linux, scripting, cron

Can you please help- need a shell script that will have a oracle query inside it and produce a .csv format output in specific location, that script should be a scheduled in a cron job which runs, the cron job should run on daily basis.

Comment: You'll be wanting to use `sqlcl`. Download: https://www.oracle.com/tools/downloads/sqlcl-downloads.html

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to write your script and use spool to save the output file in csv in the path that you want.

   ```
    #!/bin/bash

   sqlplus -silent $USER_PASS <<EOF
       SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
       SET FEEDBACK OFF
       DECLARE
          lvQuery Varchar2(32000);
       BEGIN
           select 'set heading off;' || chr(10) ||
                   'spool "TABLE_NAME.csv"' || chr(10) ||
                           'select * From TABLE_NAME;' || chr(10) ||
                           'spool off'
               Into lvQuery
               from dual;
               dbms_output.put_line(lvQuery);
       /
       EXIT
   EOF
   ```
2. After that create your script,  configure a cron to trigger the days you want to fired create your file.

`nano /etc/crontab
*  * 1 * 1-5 root    /path_to_your_file/your_shell.sh`

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to script provided by Miguel,If termout off works you can remove null device i.e `/dev/null` otherwise comment out  `SET TERMOUT OFF`.Tested on Windows sub system Ubuntu,appends timestamp to filename.

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE_NAME="/home/****/employees"
TIME_STAMP=$(date "+%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M.%S")

sqlplus.exe -s $CONN_STR <<EOF >/dev/null

-- SET TERMOUT OFF
SET PAGESIZE 3000
SET COLSEP ","
SET LINESIZE 180
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SPOOL $FILE_NAME$TIME_STAMP.csv
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES

SPOOL OFF
EXIT
EOF
```